# C# Weird Web Solution Compilation Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I'm compiling and re-compiling [BugNET](http://bugnetproject.com) over and over again.

I have the following problem. If i delete all `bin` and `obj` project folders, and re-compile under release mode, I get an error stating that `BugNET.Global` couldn't be found (the code behind for `Global.asax`)

Typical, but:

> Description: An error occurred during
>   the parsing of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review
>   the following specific parse error
>   details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   type 'BugNET.Global'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Application
>   Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
>   Inherits="BugNET.Global" Language="C#"
>   %>

Just in case.

So, the catch is that if I set the solution back in debug mode, Build, and run, the application works. If I go back to release mode, the application works, If I delete the bin / obj folders again it stops working, why? (Building under release mode after a fresh cleanup of bin and obj folders yields this error, while doing so under debug mode doesn't, and I can run under release mode too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed the compilation output folder, copying from that new folder to project\bin solved the problem.